# Get Openflow version of connected switch using opendaylight

Tags: sdn, openflow, opendaylight

I am writing a module in Opendaylight, which needs access to OF version of the connected switch.

Through Node.java + FlowCapableNode.java I am able to get little info about the switch, but I am not able to get the OF version of the switch.

I have checked multiple yang files in openflowplugin + openflowjava module's but I couldn't find OF version being exposed anywhere.

How can I get access to OF version when switch is connected?